# Python XMLRPC wordpress uploadfile

Tags: php, python, wordpress, xmlrpclib

I'm try using xmlrpclib in python to do write script upload image to website. But image could not be opened.

Here my code:

```
    import xmlrpclib
    import base64

    wp_url = "http://localhost/~mrvu/wp461/xmlrpc.php"
    wp_username = "admin"
    wp_password = "admin"
    wp_blogid = ""

    server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(wp_url)

    def upLoadImage(path):
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            data = f.read()
            img = data.encode("base64")
        data = {'name': path, 'type': 'image/jpg', 'bits': img}
        server.wp.uploadFile(wp_blogid, wp_username, wp_password, data)

    upLoadImage('g1.jpg')
```

Comment: Try with the absolute path of the file.

Comment: Thanks @t.m.adam for answered. This script and image in folder. Im try absolute path file but not ok.

Comment: The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301446/wp-uploadfile-xmlrpc-from-python-encode-base64.